# cfmail is not working properly

Tags: coldfusion, sendgrid, cfmail

I am trying to send email using following script but it's not working and throwing error:

```
<cfmail to="user@mydomain.com" 
            from="user@mydomain.com" 
           <!---  subject="#sub#"   --->
            type="html" 
            server="smtp.sendgrid.net" 
            timeout="360" 
            username="un" 
            password="psw"  >

            <cfmailparam name="X-SMTPAPI" value="{\"category\":\"Cool Emails\"}">
            <cfoutput>
                Hello
            </cfoutput>
     </cfmail>
```

Error is :Invalid token \ found on the `<cfmailparam tag line`

I have tried removing tags as well still it didn't work.

Comment: What tags did you try removing and what were the details of "still didn't work"?

Answer (score 9):

That is not how you escape quotes in CFML. You should be able to just double them up. Like so:

```
<cfmailparam name="X-SMTPAPI" value="{""category"":""Cool Emails""}">
```

Or you could use single-quotes to surround your values instead of double quotes. This will allow you to use double-quotes within your values. Like so:

```
<cfmailparam name='X-SMTPAPI' value='{"category":"Cool Emails"}'>
```

Also, in your example you do not need to use `<cfoutput>` tags within the `<cfmail>` tags.

Comment: Sometimes you do need to use cfoutput tags within a cfmail block.  This is not one of those times.

Comment: That's what I meant Dan; in the example they are not needed. I will clarify in my answer.